# partial dependence plot without using PDP package

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning

i've tried to calculate the PDP according to its definition  by writing code on python **(i don't want to use any packages)**  knowing that a PDP is calculated by :

[image]

1- With the function *f* already given as :

```
 *f* = -1.9492061 + max(0,-0.001853-X1[0])*1.0004139 +
  max(0,X1[0]- -0.001853)*1.0002827 +
  max(0,X2[0]-0.985433)*-2.7023554 +
  max(0,2.4996-X2[0])*0.7443016 +
  max(0,X2[0]-2.4996)*-3.7085839 +
  max(0,X2[0]-3.80119)*-2.3717626
```

2- And a sample of the dataset composed of X1 , X2 and Y(which is the target) columns :

[image]

The very First step is to calculate the PDP of each X1 and X2 and here's what i've done for the PDP of X1 and same apply to the X2's PDP  :

[image]

3-Now i wanted to plot the results on a plot line with the x axis as my X1 and y axis as the PDP i have calculated and here's what i got :

[image]

is the PDP's i have calculated right ?

i have followed the mathematical formulat of a PDP and seems that the results isn't correct .